# From my app, iphone call start immediately without asking confirmation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, call

is that new in 3.1?

Comment: Can you clarify?  I have no idea what you mean.  A phone call, or a method call?

Comment: i do an openUrl to make a call, and call start immediately without asking confirmation.

Also after the call the app isn't relunch.

tnx :)

Answer (score 6):

Yes, in 3.1, the behavior of the `tel:` call changed back to the way it was in 2.x. AFAIK, 3.0 is the only version that asks the user for confirmation.

Answer (score 1):

Just tried it in an another app and it placed the call without asking me first. Guess you could file a bug report if Apple if you don't think it should behave this way (personally I'm OK with it).